# selecting a mysql timestamp range

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Im trying to select a timestamp range from a mysql database and im having problems, no idea why.

I have the table  'pedido' and the field 'fecha' which is set as timestamp. I have lots of entries so that should not be the problem.

However when y select with this query:

```
 SELECT * FROM pedido WHERE fecha BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-10-10') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-11-10') ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

I get no response.

Thanls for the help

Comment: Maybe you could post the field types in your table?

Comment: @jjwdesign, the field type is `TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL does **not** store date/time data as integer.
`UNIX_TIMESTAP()` returns an integer listing the seconds since 1-1-1970.
You are comparing dates against an integer. This will never work.

Rewrite the query to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pedido 
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2011-10-10 00:00:00' AND '2011-11-10 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Note that php **does** use `unix_timestamps` So if you want to compare in php, you need to either convert to `unix_timestamp` in your SQL-statement or convert in your php code.

Comment: kind of logic when you say it

Answer (score 0):

If your column is a `TIMESTAMP` type, then it uses MySQL's default date format, NOT a Unix timestamp.  It would also be wise to call `DATE(fecha)` so that only the date parts are compared, ignoring hours,minutes,seconds.

```
SELECT * 
FROM pedido 
WHERE DATE(fecha) BETWEEN '2011-10-10' AND '2011-11-10' 
ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Comment: That will kill any change of using an index, besides `BETWEEN` is all inclusive, so if you want to avoid **that** issue, just do `WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2011-10-10' AND '2011-11-10 23:59:59'` this will be much much faster if `fecha` is indexed.